# He's dead, Jim: is there a memory limit on the number of circles that can be drawn on a Google map?

Tags: google-maps, memory-leaks

On a map of the USA, I have been asked to draw 50,000 circles each with a 5000-yard radius.

The lat-lon locations are scattered throughout the country, but a large number of these circles overlap. Opacity is set to 0.05; regions with many superimposed circles become more opaque.

The circles start to appear, but after about 30 seconds Chrome crashes, displaying the "He's dead, Jim" message.

Comment: I don't know for circle but for polygon I draw more than 100.000 polygon and no crashes in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. I guess is a memory leaks and not a browser problem.

Comment: The only limits are those due to your computer, operating system and browser.  You seem to be exceeding those.  Of course it could also be an error (or inefficiency) in the way you implemented that functionality, but can't say without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

About the error message:

According to [Error: "He's Dead, Jim!"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1270364?hl=en):

> You might see the “He’s Dead, Jim!” message in a tab if:
>
> - You don’t have enough memory available to run the tab. Computers rely    on memory to run apps, extensions, and programs. Low memory
>     can cause    them to run slowly or stop working.
> - You stopped a process using Google Chrome's Task Manager, the    system's task manager, or a command line tool.

---

It evidently occurs since you are trying to render **50k** objects. In order to render such amount of objects I would recommend to consider [Overlay approach](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays). In that case the performance could be improved considerably since city icons could ve rendered via `canvas` element instead of `div` ones.

Having said that, the below example demonstrates how to render multiple amount of cities (`1000` cities ) using the described approach:

```js
var overlay;
USCitiesOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function USCitiesOverlay(map) {
    this._map = map;
    this._cities = [];
    this._radius = 6;
    this._container = document.createElement("div");
    this._container.id = "citieslayer";
    this.setMap(map);
    this.addCity = function (lat, lng) {
        this._cities.push({position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)});
    };
}


USCitiesOverlay.prototype.createCityIcon = function (id,pos) {
    /*var cityIcon = document.createElement('div');
    cityIcon.setAttribute('id', "cityicon_" + id);
    cityIcon.style.position = 'absolute';
    cityIcon.style.left = (pos.x - this._radius) + 'px';
    cityIcon.style.top = (pos.y - this._radius) + 'px';
    cityIcon.style.width = cityIcon.style.height = (this._radius * 2) + 'px';
    cityIcon.className = "circleBase city";
    return cityIcon;*/

   
    var cityIcon = document.createElement('canvas');

    cityIcon.id = 'cityicon_' + id;
    cityIcon.width = cityIcon.height = this._radius * 2;
    cityIcon.style.width = cityIcon.width + 'px';
    cityIcon.style.height = cityIcon.height + 'px';
    cityIcon.style.left = (pos.x - this._radius) + 'px';  
    cityIcon.style.top = (pos.y - this._radius) + 'px'; 
    cityIcon.style.position = "absolute";

    var centerX = cityIcon.width / 2;
    var centerY = cityIcon.height / 2;
    var ctx = cityIcon.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(160,16,0,0.6)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, this._radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    return cityIcon;
};    


USCitiesOverlay.prototype.ensureCityIcon = function (id,pos) {
    var cityIcon = document.getElementById("cityicon_" + id);
    if(cityIcon){
        cityIcon.style.left = (pos.x - this._radius) + 'px';
        cityIcon.style.top = (pos.y - this._radius) + 'px';
        return cityIcon;
    }
    return this.createCityIcon(id,pos);
};    



USCitiesOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(this._container);
};



USCitiesOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
    var zoom = this._map.getZoom();
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    var container = this._container;
    
    this._cities.forEach(function(city,idx){
        var xy = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(city.position);
        var cityIcon = overlay.ensureCityIcon(idx,xy);
        container.appendChild(cityIcon);    
    });
   
};

USCitiesOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container);
    this._container = null;
};







function getRandomInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


function generateCityMap(count) {
    var citymap = [];

    var minPos = new google.maps.LatLng(49.25, -123.1);
    var maxPos = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -74.005973);
    

    for(var i = 0; i < count;i++)
    {
       var lat = getRandomInterval(minPos.lat(),maxPos.lat());
       var lng = getRandomInterval(minPos.lng(),maxPos.lng());
       var population = getRandomInterval(10000,1000000);


       citymap.push({
          location: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          population: population
       });

    }

    return citymap;
}




function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    overlay = new USCitiesOverlay(map);
    overlay.addCity(40.714352, -74.005973);   //chicago
    overlay.addCity(40.714352, -74.005973);   //newyork
    overlay.addCity(34.052234, -118.243684);   //losangeles
    overlay.addCity(49.25, -123.1);   //vancouver

    var citymap = generateCityMap(1000);
    citymap.forEach(function(city){
          overlay.addCity(city.location.lat(), city.location.lng());   
    });    

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply with a code example, Vadim. The problem with the overlay approach (which I did not mention in my original question) is that the overlay image does not scale when the map is resized.  The drawn circles do scale with the zoom-level.

Comment: What I would like is for Google to offer a draw circle "lite" version, where the circle is not interactive; each circle then could consume less memory.